# Error making a squirrel distributable for win32/x64 - Electron-Forge App

Tags: electron, electron-forge, squirrel.windows

I installed `Wine` in Ubuntu 22.04 and I executed `yarn make --platform=win32` in order to produce the `.exe` executable Electron file, I get some strange errors:

```
raphy@raohy:~/ForgeTypescriptReactWebpack$ yarn make --platform=win32
yarn run v1.22.19
$ electron-forge make --platform=win32
✔ Checking your system
✔ Loading configuration
✔ Resolving make targets
  › Making for the following targets: squirrel, zip
✔ Running package command
  ✔ Preparing to package application
  ✔ Running packaging hooks
    ✔ Running generateAssets hook
    ✔ Running prePackage hook
      ✔ [plugin-webpack] Preparing native dependencies: 1 / 1
      ✔ [plugin-webpack] Building webpack bundles
  ✔ Packaging application
    ✔ Packaging for x64 on win32 [27s]
  ✔ Running postPackage hook
✔ Running preMake hook
❯ Making distributables
  ✖ Making a squirrel distributable for win32/x64
    › spawn mono ENOENT
  ◼ Making a zip distributable for win32/x64
◼ Running postMake hook

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: spawn mono ENOENT
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
raphy@raohy:~/ForgeTypescriptReactWebpack$
```

In `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "make": "electron-forge make",
}
```

Executing via Wine the produced `.exe` file I get this:

raphy@raohy:~$ wine /home/raphy/ForgeTypescriptReactWebpack/out/forgetypescriptreactwebpack-win32-x64/forgetypescriptreactwebpack.exe
0100:err:winediag:ntlm_check_version ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
0100:err:ntlm:ntlm_LsaApInitializePackage no NTLM support, expect problems
0100:fixme:powrprof:PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification (0x00000002,000000000081FCF0,000000000081FCE8) stub!
0104:fixme:process:NtQueryInformationProcess (0xffffffffffffffff,info_class=49,0x19efc38,0x00000008,(nil)) Unknown information class
0100:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0000000000000000 1 0000000000000000 0 stub

```
0100:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 2, 000005180029CDB0, 16) stub
0100:fixme:nls:RtlGetThreadPreferredUILanguages 00000038, 000000000081F56C, 0000000000000000 000000000081F568
0100:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x38 000000000081F56C 0000000000000000 000000000081F568) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0100:fixme:nls:RtlGetThreadPreferredUILanguages 00000038, 000000000081F56C, 000000000081F552 000000000081F568
0100:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x38 000000000081F56C 000000000081F552 000000000081F568) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0100:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
0128:fixme:kernelbase:AppPolicyGetThreadInitializationType FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA, 0000000006DEFE10
0100:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x880360, 1): stub
0100:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0000000000010062, 0000000000880360): stub
0070:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x25e1b0, 0): stub
0070:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0000000000010020, 000000000025E1B0): stub
0100:fixme:winsock:WSALookupServiceBeginW (000000000081F000 0x00000ff0 000000000081F078) Stub!
[252:0105/192543.562:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(225)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 0
0100:fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 000000000081F1D8, overlapped 0000051800320090): stub
0100:fixme:win:GetPointerDevices (000000000081EB3C 0000000000000000): partial stub
0100:fixme:system:QueryDisplayConfig (00000002 000000000081EB50 0000051800278A70 000000000081EB40 0000051800688300 0000000000000000): semi-stub
0100:fixme:system:DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo Unimplemented packet type: 11
0140:fixme:wtsapi:WTSRegisterSessionNotification Stub 0000000000020052 0x00000000
0154:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000CCFEF98 0000000000000000 len=0 000000000CCFEF9C),stub!
0154:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000CCFEF98 00000518007583D0 len=40 000000000CCFEF9C),stub!
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtSetInformationToken TokenIntegrityLevel stub!
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken flags 0x1 unsupported
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken support for restricting sids not yet implemented
0100:fixme:service:I_ScRegisterDeviceNotification Notification filters are not yet implemented.
0100:fixme:system:EnableNonClientDpiScaling (0000000000020058): stub
0100:fixme:win:RegisterTouchWindow (0000000000020058 00000002): stub
0140:fixme:wtsapi:WTSRegisterSessionNotification Stub 0000000000020056 0x00000000
0100:fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0000000000020058, 2, 000000000081D684, 4) stub
0114:fixme:file:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
0150:fixme:file:ReplaceFileW Ignoring flags 2
011c:fixme:file:ReplaceFileW Ignoring flags 2
0100:fixme:nls:RtlGetThreadPreferredUILanguages 00000038, 000000000081CA6C, 0000000000000000 000000000081CA68
0100:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x38 000000000081CA6C 0000000000000000 000000000081CA68) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0100:fixme:nls:RtlGetThreadPreferredUILanguages 00000038, 000000000081CA6C, 000000000081CA52 000000000081CA68
0100:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x38 000000000081CA6C 000000000081CA52 000000000081CA68) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0100:fixme:dwrite:dwritefontface5_HasVariations 0000000000ED0A60: stub
0100:fixme:win:RegisterPowerSettingNotification (0000000000020056,{2b84c20e-ad23-4ddf-93db-05ffbd7efca5},0): stub
0184:fixme:dwmapi:DwmGetWindowAttribute (0000000000020058 14 0000000010E7F5AC 4) stub
0100:fixme:win:GetPointerDevices (000000000081C80C 0000000000000000): partial stub
0100:fixme:system:QueryDisplayConfig (00000002 000000000081C820 0000051800ADB570 000000000081C810 0000051800AEF380 0000000000000000): semi-stub
0114:fixme:file:ReplaceFileW Ignoring flags 2
0100:fixme:system:DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo Unimplemented packet type: 11
0100:fixme:msctf:SetInputScopes STUB: 0000000000020058 ... (null) (null)
MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY:  file://Z:\home\raphy\ForgeTypescriptReactWebpack\out\forgetypescriptreactwebpack-win32-x64\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\
main_window\index.html
0100:fixme:shcore:GetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID 000000000081CC60: stub
0100:fixme:win:RegisterTouchWindow (0000000000010080 00000002): stub
[252:0105/192544.046:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(968)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=49
0184:fixme:dwmapi:DwmGetWindowAttribute (0000000000020058 14 0000000010E7F2CC 4) stub
0180:err:winediag:ntlm_check_version ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
0180:err:ntlm:ntlm_LsaApInitializePackage no NTLM support, expect problems
0180:fixme:powrprof:PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification (0x00000002,000000000081FCF0,000000000081FCE8) stub!
019c:fixme:process:NtQueryInformationProcess (0xffffffffffffffff,info_class=49,0x19efc38,0x00000008,(nil)) Unknown information class
0180:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0000000000000000 1 0000000000000000 0 stub
0180:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 2, 000004CE002ACCF0, 16) stub
01b4:fixme:winsock:WSALookupServiceBeginW (0000000005ADDC10 0x00000ff0 0000000005ADDC88) Stub!
[380:0105/192544.150:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(225)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 0
01b4:fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0000000005ADDDE8, overlapped 000004CE0031CB10): stub
01b4:fixme:wlanapi:WlanEnumInterfaces (0000000000000001, 0000000000000000, 0000000005ADCE68) semi-stub
01b4:fixme:wlanapi:WlanEnumInterfaces (0000000000000001, 0000000000000000, 0000000005ADCE68) semi-stub
01b4:fixme:winsock:setsockopt Ignoring SO_RANDOMIZE_PORT
0100:fixme:msctf:SetInputScopes STUB: 0000000000020058 ... (null) (null)
0100:fixme:msctf:SetInputScopes STUB: 0000000000020058 ... (null) (null)
0198:err:winediag:ntlm_check_version ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
0198:err:ntlm:ntlm_LsaApInitializePackage no NTLM support, expect problems
0198:fixme:powrprof:PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification (0x00000002,000000000081FCF0,000000000081FCE8) stub!
01d4:fixme:process:NtQueryInformationProcess (0xffffffffffffffff,info_class=49,0x19efc38,0x00000008,(nil)) Unknown information class
0198:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0000000000000000 1 0000000000000000 0 stub
0198:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 2, 000000CA002A0F30, 16) stub
0198:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
0198:fixme:thread:QueryThreadCycleTime (FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE,000000000081EAE8): stub!
0218:fixme:kernelbase:AppPolicyGetThreadInitializationType FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA, 000000000B63FE10
0154:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000CCFEF98 0000000000000000 len=0 000000000CCFEF9C),stub!
0154:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000CCFEF98 0000051800758340 len=40 000000000CCFEF9C),stub!
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtSetInformationToken TokenIntegrityLevel stub!
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken flags 0x1 unsupported
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken support for restricting sids not yet implemented
[252:0105/192544.356:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(968)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=49
0154:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000CCFEF98 0000000000000000 len=0 000000000CCFEF9C),stub!
0154:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000CCFEF98 0000051800BAF620 len=40 000000000CCFEF9C),stub!
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtSetInformationToken TokenIntegrityLevel stub!
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken flags 0x1 unsupported
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken support for restricting sids not yet implemented
[252:0105/192544.545:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(968)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=49
0154:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000CCFEF98 0000000000000000 len=0 000000000CCFEF9C),stub!
0154:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000CCFEF98 0000051800CA6BE0 len=40 000000000CCFEF9C),stub!
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtSetInformationToken TokenIntegrityLevel stub!
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken flags 0x1 unsupported
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken support for restricting sids not yet implemented
[252:0105/192544.729:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(968)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=49
0154:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000CCFEF98 0000000000000000 len=0 000000000CCFEF9C),stub!
0154:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000CCFEF98 0000051800BAFC20 len=40 000000000CCFEF9C),stub!
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtSetInformationToken TokenIntegrityLevel stub!
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken flags 0x1 unsupported
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken support for restricting sids not yet implemented
[252:0105/192544.911:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(968)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=49
0154:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000CCFEF98 0000000000000000 len=0 000000000CCFEF9C),stub!
0154:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000CCFEF98 0000051800CA64F0 len=40 000000000CCFEF9C),stub!
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtSetInformationToken TokenIntegrityLevel stub!
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken flags 0x1 unsupported
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken support for restricting sids not yet implemented
[252:0105/192545.094:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(968)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=49
0154:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000CCFEF98 0000000000000000 len=0 000000000CCFEF9C),stub!
0154:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000CCFEF98 00000518007541A0 len=40 000000000CCFEF9C),stub!
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtSetInformationToken TokenIntegrityLevel stub!
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken flags 0x1 unsupported
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken support for restricting sids not yet implemented
[252:0105/192545.279:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(968)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=49
01b4:fixme:winsock:setsockopt Ignoring SO_RANDOMIZE_PORT
01b4:fixme:winsock:setsockopt Ignoring SO_RANDOMIZE_PORT
0154:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000CCFEF98 0000000000000000 len=0 000000000CCFEF9C),stub!
0154:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000CCFEF98 0000051800BAFE90 len=40 000000000CCFEF9C),stub!
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtSetInformationToken TokenIntegrityLevel stub!
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken flags 0x1 unsupported
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken support for restricting sids not yet implemented
[252:0105/192545.464:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(968)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=49
0154:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000CCFEF98 0000000000000000 len=0 000000000CCFEF9C),stub!
0154:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000CCFEF98 0000051800CABF50 len=40 000000000CCFEF9C),stub!
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtSetInformationToken TokenIntegrityLevel stub!
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken flags 0x1 unsupported
0154:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken support for restricting sids not yet implemented
[252:0105/192545.671:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(968)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=49
[252:0105/192545.671:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(450)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
wine: Unhandled exception 0x80000003 in thread 100 at address 000000014172A56F (thread 0100), starting debugger...
0224:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x254810, 1): stub
0224:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (000000000001009A, 0000000000254810): stub
01b4:fixme:winsock:setsockopt Ignoring SO_RANDOMIZE_PORT
01c8:fixme:file:ReplaceFileW Ignoring flags 2
01c8:fixme:file:ReplaceFileW Ignoring flags 2
wine: Read access denied for device L"\\??\\Z:\\", FS volume label and serial are not available.
wine: Read access denied for device L"\\??\\Z:\\", FS volume label and serial are not available.
```

[image]

[image]

Here the `backtrace` got clicking `"Show Details"` in the `program error` window :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sDAsIFyWlHQ0fxMM3nZ8d4R4orFJTgGK/view?usp=share_link

From the command-line output: [image] I guess that something wrong happens during the making of the `squirrel distributable for win32/x64`

Other info:

```
Electron : 19
node : 18
```

How to debug and detect the root causes of the issue?
How to make it work?